# How to stop linear rectangle movement from stuttering in sdl2

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the code for moving the rectangle while w is pressed

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            done = false;
        }
        if (e.type = SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_w:
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);
                player.y -=SPEED;
                draw();
                break;
            case SDLK_s:
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);
                player.y +=SPEED;
                draw();
                break;
            default:
                break;

            }

        }
    }
```

everything works fine except when it runs it stutters. the rectangle moves by stuttering and it's very annoying

Comment: If e.type == const or enum it will not also equal another const/enum. Make the second `if` an `else if` . In the second `if` you are assigning a value and testing the assigned value as not zero. Change the `=` to `==`

Comment: Usually, updating the value every time key event occurs is not a good idea since it depends on your key-repeat rate of your OS. I would suggest that holding speed variable in the player object(or somewhere else), then update the player's position with the speed variable every frame in your game loop. Plus you will need to handle SDL_KEYUP event to unset the speed.

Comment: lookup for your FPS, if you want "speed per second" use delta time, otherwise its speed per frame which vary. in main loop "calc delta time" "poll events" "update" and "draw" (do not draw only or redraw entire screen when key is pressed)